# Why to scroll webpage to top, i need to scroll the $("html")

Tags: jquery

i am referencing the code from [snipplr](http://snipplr.com/view/8782/jquery-animated-scroll-to-top/)

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
```

i found out actually i need to use `$('html')`, `$('body')` does not work, `$('html, body')` seems redundant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this blog post](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/improved-animated-scrolling-script-for-same-page-links) (update 4) it's because `html` works for IE in standards mode and `body` works in quirks mode.